# libcompression.dylib not loaded

Tags: c++, xcode

I work on OS X Yosemite and recently experience multiple problems. All of them concern the error:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libcompression.dylib
```

For example, XCode never opens even though it was deleted and reinstalled several times:

```
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTXConnectionServices.framework/Versions/A/DTXConnectionServices
  Reason: image not found
```

I can neither update my Zsh, nor load boost libraries. All those give me an error with libcompression.dylib but I have no idea how to fix this point.

Thank you in advance for your help!